# Ratio test(Complex): To prove that the radius of convergence lies between the limit infimum limit supremum of $\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have the following problem:
[image: page1]

My question is how do I proceed. I am looking for a general outline. I understand the $lim inf$ to be the limit to which the lower bound of the tail of a sequence converges, and similarly the supremum. I already know what is stated, that is if the limit exists then $lim_{ n\to \infty} \frac{|a_n|}{a_{n+1}|} = R = lim  inf_{n \to \infty} |a_{n}|^{-1/n}$. I am unfamiliar with working with limit infimum and limit supremum.

Comment: The most basic hint for working with the ration test: comparison with geometric series.

Comment: can you elaborate @GEdgar?

Comment: If $|z-z_0| > \limsup$ then diverges since $|a_n(z-z_0)^n| \to \infty$.  If $|z-z_0| < \liminf$, then converges by comparison with a geometric series $\sum a r^n$ where
$|z-z_0|/\liminf < r < 1$.  That's the idea: but check if you want $|a_{n+1}| / |a_n|$ instead of the reciprocal.

Answer (score 1):

For any $N$ you can focus on the tail sum $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^n$.

Note that if $n \ge N$ then $|a_n| = |a_N| \frac{|a_{N+1}|}{|a_N|} \cdots \frac{|a_{n}|}{|a_{n-1}|} \le |a_N| \left(\sup_{m \ge N} \frac{|a_{m+1}|}{|a_m|}\right)^{n-N}$.

Applying this bound to each $|a_n|$ for $n \ge N$ yields $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty |a_n| |z-z_0|^n \le |a_N| |z-z_0|^N \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(|z-z_0|\sup_{m \ge N} \frac{|a_{m+1}|}{|a_m|}\right)^{k}.$$
If $|z-z_0| < \frac{1}{\sup_{m \ge N} \frac{|a_{m+1}|}{|a_m|}} = \inf_{m \ge N} \frac{|a_m|}{|a_{m+1}|}$ then the series on the right-hand side is a geometric series that converges. Thus the original series converges if $|z-z_0| < \inf_{m \ge N} \frac{|a_m|}{|a_{m+1}|}$. This holds for any $N$, so taking $N \to \infty$ shows that the original series converges if $|z-z_0| < \lim\inf_{m \to \infty} \frac{|a_m|}{|a_{m+1}|}$, i.e. this liminf is a lower bound for the radius of convergence.

Comment: Thank you @angryavian! And can I now say $|z-z_{0}| > \frac{1}{liminf_{m \to \infty} \frac{|a_m|}{|a_{m+1}|} = lim sup _{m \to \infty}\frac{|a_m|}{|a_{m+1|}}$

Comment: if $|z-z_0| < lim inf_{m \to infty} \frac{|a_m|}{|a_{m+1}}$, how does it prove that the radius of convergence R > lim inf of the said quantity?

Comment: @curious_analyst For some value of $L$, I've shown that if $|z-z_0| < L$ then the series converges. The radius of convergence is the largest such $L$ for which this is true.

Comment: Thanks @angryavian